# Using HTTPWebRequest in ASP.NET VB

Tags: .net, asp.net, http, httpwebrequest

I don't have any idea how to use this class in .net. Anyone wants to share his knowledge how to implement and use this class?

Have you got any simple procedure that calls a page and process it?

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Dim request = HttpWebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com")
Dim response = request.GetResponse()
Using reader = New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
    Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd())
End Using
```

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way is to use the `WebClient` class that simplifies most common uses of HttpWebRequest.

Example in C#:

```
string page;
using (WebClient client = new WebClient()) {
   page = client.DownloadString("http://www.guffa.com");
}
```