# get a website data and display on my web page

Tags: asp.net, webpage-rendering

I am Trying to display a website portion on my web page.and for this i dnt want to use iframe.But any other idea which can get data from a website and then display it on my web page like.
this is website
http://www.sugaronline.com/

and want to display this portion on m y web page

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CVsrh.jpg

Please any one tell me is there any way to do this except using iframe?

**Update**

```
 Shared Function GetHtmlPage(ByVal strURL As String) As String
        Dim strResult As String
        Dim objResponse As WebResponse
        Dim objRequest As WebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(strURL)
        objResponse = objRequest.GetResponse()
        Using sr As New StreamReader(objResponse.GetResponseStream())
            strResult = sr.ReadToEnd()
            sr.Close()
        End Using
        Return strResult
    End Function

Dim responses As String = GetHtmlPage(theurl)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PHP, try using CURL, it is a server side request which fetches the data from the target site and then you can embed it in your page.

On the other hand, if you are using .Net, you can use httpwebrequest to do the same.

In short, you will have to make a server side request from your server to the target website to fetch the data and you can embed that data on your page as if it has come from your website.

Please check out this post

[How to use httpwebrequest to pull image from website to local file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2368115/how-to-use-httpwebrequest-to-pull-image-from-website-to-local-file)

Here all you need to do is

when you have the image bytes ready, you need to write those bytes to response but before that, you will have to send proper headers to let the browser understand that you are now going to send the image.

Comment: Sir I know About `httpwebrequest` but please show me sample to do exactly as i require in my question

Comment: Sir I am using asp.net with vb.net

Comment: I am sorry but I have never worked with vb.net. Probably you might be able to convert the code to suit the vb.net syntax

Comment: Further, I've just read your updated question. What you are missing is, you need to get only that part of page which you want to show. You have multiple options to do it, one is to use the html parsing using many of the libs available and another is to use regular expression to find the data of your interest.

Comment: For this I have questioned on stack please show me any example to do this

Comment: malik.adeel@shakarganj.com.pk

Comment: R u there Sir? U have not Send Me email

Answer (score 0):

Refer existing posts

[Using HTTPWebRequest in ASP.NET VB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/906543/using-httpwebrequest-in-asp-net-vb)

or simply [Google this](https://www.google.com/search?q=using%20webrequest%20asp.net&oq=using%20webrequest%20asp.net&sugexp=chrome,mod=0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&tbo=d&q=site:%20stackoverflow.com%20using%20httpwebrequest%20asp.net&sa=X&ei=YNKlUPuDEs7migKFl4HIBw&ved=0CC0Q7xYoAA&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=8d44242ae547b3f7&bpcl=38625945&biw=1280&bih=935)

Comment: Please View My Upate I do that but Question is that now how can i diplay like http://i.stack.imgur.com/CVsrh.jpg ?